# Is memcpy OK in buffer reallocation?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memcpy

Prior to C++11 move semantics, if you have a buffer that needs to be reallocated, for instance in a std::vector implementation where a call to push_back results in a reallocation, is it OK to just memcpy the old buffer contents into the new buffer, or should you iterate through the old buffer and copy-construct each element into the new buffer?

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::copy`, it should be optimized as completely as the compiler writers will allow.

Answer (score 3):

Move semantics do not magically make objects `memcpy`able. For example:

```
struct S {
    S(int ii) : i(ii), ip(&i) { }
    int i;
    int *ip; // points to i
};
```

When an object of this type is copied or moved, the value of `ip` in the copy cannot be the value from the original object; it has to be changed to point to the `i` member of the new object. `memcpy` will **not** get this right; it will copy the old address into the new object, and the result will be nonsense. The copy constructor and move constructor have to set `ip` correctly.

As @markransom says, use `std::copy`. It will get the semantics right; in particular, for types that can be copied with `memcpy` it will (usually) do so.